# MSBuild Compile target to generate a dll for a class?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuild-buildengine

I have a VB Class and when I run :

```
msbuild /t:Compile
```

It generates the Exe for the application that contains the compiled code for the class as well.

I want to have a separate dll for my VB class in myfolder Folder.

```
What extra arguments do I have to pass, in order to get my dll in myfolder ?
```

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by invoking the Compile Task of MSbuild.

So, Writing a task to use the VBC compiler task to compile the class to a dll will do the trick.

Rest, the default compile task will generate the exe for the main module.

That is how !

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the standard Visual Studio convention for the MSBuild scripts (and you probably are), then a single `.vbproj` maps to a single output assembly (either `.exe` or `.dll`). The output format is set by the `OutputType` property. To generate two output assemblies, you'll want to create two project files, and tie them together either using a solution file (you can use Visual Studio to generate it and then use MSBuild for compiling from command line) or you can create a `.proj` file to bundle them. Such a bundle project would look as follows:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="**\*proj" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects ="@(ProjectsToBuild)"
             ContinueOnError ="false"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
        <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: **Well,** Well its fine that it will generate only 1 exe/dll but, I figured out a better way, by calling the Vbc task from the Build target and custom compiling our code to dll, in this way - I got both exe and dll with a single project file.

Comment: I will argue that a single project file is not better, as Visual Studio will not fully understand such setup. You might not need it now, but needlessly going against the standard is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your project into 2 projects. 1) .EXE containing your main() and 2) containing all of the library classes. The .EXE project then references the .DLL project.

Rebuilding the same project twice to get a .dll and a .exe is pretty strange. Why not cleanly separate the concerns?

Comment: That's what !
But I think that this can be done without 2 project files and in 1 build process.. !